# Using Ordinal axis to render scatter plot in D3

Tags: d3.js

My data looks as below:

var sampleData = [{
  "x": 'GOOG',
  "y": 5
}, {
  "x": 'FB',
  "y": 20
}, {
  "x": 'MSFT',
  "y": 10
}, {
  "x": 'EBAY',
  "y": 40
}, {
  "x": 'AMZN',
  "y": 5
}, {
  "x": 'AAPL',
  "y": 60
}];

x axis represents the stock name and y axis represents the number of stocks.

I am trying to represent the same using scatter plot where x axis will be ordinal (representing stock name) and y-axis will be number of stocks.

My code is below. Nothing gets rendered as such.

```
var vis = d3.select("#svgVisualize");

  var yMax = d3.max(sampleData, function(point) {return point.y;});

  //step 1 : scale the data

  var xange = d3.scale.ordinal();
  var yRange = d3.scale.linear().range([400, 40]).domain([0,yMax]);


  //step 2: scale the axis
  var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xRange);
  var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(yRange).orient("left");

  //Step3: append the x and y axis
  vis.append('svg:g').call(xAxis).attr("transform", "translate(0,400)");
  vis.append('svg:g').call(yAxis).attr("transform", "translate(40,0)");

  var circles = vis.selectAll("circle").data(sampleData);

  circles
    .enter()
    .insert("circle")
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return xRange (d.x); })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return xRange (d.x); })
    .attr("r", 10)
    .style("fill", "red");
```

Plnkr available here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/5v76uKi5wDK65H2GGqVn

Answer (score 1):

I made a couple of changes in this updated Plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/YDUxLQWg5tiIBN5eBHkf (although there's still some axis positioning to sort out).

First, the console was showing an error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: xRange is not defined". That's just a typo, change:

```
var xange = d3.scale.ordinal();
```

to

```
var xRange = d3.scale.ordinal();
```

Next, even for ordinal scales you need to define the `range` and `domain`. I added:

```
var xRange = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(sampleData.map(function(d) { return d.x; }))
    .rangePoints([0, 400]);
```

The `domain` is all `x` values from the data, and these are evenly spaced along the 400px axis using [`rangePoints`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales#ordinal_rangePoints)

Finally I changed how your circles' `dy` attribute was being calculated (was using `x` values, presume a copy-paste error):

```
.attr("cy", function(d) { return xRange(d.x); })
```

to

```
.attr("cy", function(d) { return yRange(d.y); })
```

Comment: This helped me a lot. Thanks!